# I have client-side JS making tons of request. How can I have my server cache this content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, client-server, getjson

Kind of a strange and super novice question. I have client-side JS making API calls via `getJSON`, etc.

This content won't change on a second-by-second basis, so I want to store the results on my server, and have the clients simply pull down data from there.

Yet, I've already implemented this whole application to be client-side fetching of the APIs. This is likely an absurd question, but is there any quick way I could get my server to cache the results of these requests without completely rewriting my code to be server-side fetching? For example, could I somehow run the client-side code on my server and somehow cache it there, and have new people visiting my site pull the data from my server?

Comment: I would first recommend reducing the number of requests sent from JS, and considering client-side caching first

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in the XMLHttpRequest request headers. In jQuery, that means [setting the `cache` flag](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

And, this is a good [primer on caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) in general.

Comment: He seems to be using jQuery `getJSON`